# CSV to TSV without replacing commas within quotes

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv, tr

All the CSV to TSV tutorials are suggesting a simple:

```
tr ',' '\t'
```

though some CSVs look like this:

```
1,310,"IntAct,PINA"
```

in which case I would like to keep `"IntAct,PINA"`:

```
1   310 "IntAct,PINA"
```

How could I parameterize the `tr` command (or `sed`, etc.) in order to do that?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: did you have you try any of the answers?

Answer (score 2):

Use `csvformat` from [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io):

```
csvformat -d, -D$'\t' file
```

or shorter:

```
csvformat -T file
```

> `-d` input delimiter (not needed here, as `,` is the default input delimiter)
>
> `-D` output delimiter
>
> `-T` set tabs as output delimiter

It will remove the quotes, as they are not needed for a `tsv`.

---

You should be able to install `csvkit` via `pip`:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
pip install csvkit
```

Comment: ... FWIW I had a bit of a play with the quoting options and it seems you can use `-U2` to force quoting of the non-numeric field in the output, but it only works if you use `-u2` for the input format - which appears to force floating-point conversion as well

Answer (score 0):

If `csvkit` (which I recommend) is not available, then you could use the perl [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module:

```
perl -MText::CSV -lne '
  BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new} print join "\t", $p->fields() if $p->parse($_)
' file
```

If you insist on retaining the quoting (which is unnecessary, since the embedded `,` is no longer a separator), then you could do something like

```
print join "\t", map { $_ =~ s/.*,.*/"$&"/r } $p->fields() if $p->parse($_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your CSV without heading

```
1,310,"IntAct,PINA"
```

and Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)

```
mlr --nidx --ifs "," --ofs "\t" cat input.csv
```

gives you back

```
1       310     "IntAct PINA"
```